# A nested include does not deliver result

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three associated models, Product, CatalogMembership, Catalog with these associations

```
Product.hasMany(CatalogMembership, { foreignKey: 'product_id' });
CatalogMembership.hasOne(Catalog, { targetKey: 'catalog_id', foreignKey: 'id' });
```

When I perform this nested query

```
let products = await Product.findAll({
      where: {...},
      include: {
        model: CatalogMembership,
        where: { catalog_id: { [Op.in]: catalogIds } },
        include: {
          model: Catalog,
          attributes: ['name', 'id'],
        },
      },
    });
```

The CatalogMemberships are included, but the catalog is null:

```
console.log(products[0]) // -->
/*
{
  id: 1,
  catalog_memberships: [
    { id: 23,
      catalog_id: 15,
      catalog: null,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 24,
      catalog_id: 16,
      catalog: null,
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
*/
```

And I'm sure that there are catalogs with
`CatalogMembership.catalog_id === Catalog.id`

I expected to not get null for the catalog attribute but something like

```
{
  id: 15,
  name: 'MyCatalog'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **targetKey** in [hasOne](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-hasOne) Relation. There is **foreignKey** (name of the foreign key attribute in the target table) and **sourceKey** to (name of the attribute to use as the key for the association in the source table), which is by default primary key of source table.

So use like this,

```
CatalogMembership.hasOne(Catalog, { foreignKey: 'catalog_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Ved. Unfortunately my general approach was wrong. I have to build an n:m association with Product and Catalog through CatalogMembership. So I added a belongsToMany association to Product and Catalog.

Here is the code:

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
  <some column names>
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  ...
});

const Catalog = sequelize.define('catalog', {
  <some column names>
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  ...
});


const CatalogMembership = sequelize.define('catalog_membership', {
  product_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
  catalog_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  ...
});

Product.belongsToMany(Catalog, { through: CatalogMembership, foreignKey: 'product_id', otherKey: 'catalog_id' });
Catalog.belongsToMany(Product, { through: CatalogMembership, foreignKey: 'catalog_id', otherKey: 'product_id' });

if (Meteor.isTest) {
  Product.sync();
  Catalog.sync();
  CatalogMembership.sync();
}
```

With these associations a nested query isn't necessary:

```
let products = await Product.findAll({
      where: { ... },
      include: {
        model: Catalog,
        where: { id: { [Op.in]: catalogPostgresIds } },
        attributes: ['name', 'id'],
      },
      order: { ... },
    });
```